# AWS CLI Loading Output Onto Multiple Lines

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli

I am using the aws cli to give me some output which I require in .csv format.

The below shows the commands I've put together:

```
aws ec2 describe-instances --output text --query 'Reservations[*].Instances[*].[VpcId, SubnetId, InstanceId, InstanceType, ImageId, State.Name, LaunchTime, Placement.AvailabilityZone, Placement.Tenancy, PrivateIpAddress, PrivateDnsName, PublicDnsName,[Tags[?Key==`Name`].Value],[Tags[?Key==`PowerData`].Value] ]' --output text | sed -E 's/\s+/,/g'
```

For some reason, the final two pieces of info, "Name" and "PowerData" end up on separate lines. This screws up my formatting when I open it up in a spreadsheet.

Anyone have any ideas on what might be causing that or how I may resolve it please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason is TAGs return array so you need to print the only value on `0` index to display the `TAGs` on a single line.
You can verify this

```
aws ec2 describe-instances --output json --query 'Reservations[*].Instances[*].Tags[]'
```

output

```
    [
        {
            "Key": "Name",
            "Value": "demo"
        },
        {
            "Key": "PowerData",
            "Value": "demo"
        }
    ]
```

so you need pipe expression

```
Tags[?Key==`Name`].Value| [0]
```

With the addition of filters, we could pass the result of one expression to another, operating on the result of a projection (or any expression).

Expression:

```
foo.*.bar | [0]
```

[jmespath-pipe-expressions](https://jmespath.org/proposals/pipes.html#pipe-expressions)

So try this

```
aws ec2 describe-instances --output text --query 'Reservations[*].Instances[*].[VpcId, SubnetId, InstanceId, InstanceType, ImageId, State.Name, LaunchTime, Placement.AvailabilityZone, Placement.Tenancy, PrivateIpAddress, PrivateDnsName, PublicDnsName,Tags[?Key==`Name`].Value| [0],Tags[?Key==`PowerData`].Value | [0] ]' --output text | sed -E 's/\s+/,/g'
```

Comment: You are a beautiful human being. Loving your work :-)